# How do you write this mathematica code to Python?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

[I don't know how to put this Mathematica code into Python code. That's the image link where it shows my code.]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/58ATE.png

Comment: Please edit your question to show us the code.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [Mathics](https://github.com/Mathics3/mathics-core) project on Github which might help to solve your problem. But I'm not sure if all the functions you need are available.